# Pins and needles after removing nettles

Tags: weeds

I have been experiencing pins and needles in my left hand which I've had for over a week.  I was clearing a large area in the garden from nettles and during this time I was stung numerous times.

Is this a result of being stung and when can I expect this feeling to go away?

I did wear gloves, but this weren't thick enough.

Comment: In my experience the pain and/or red skin from nettle stings goes away within 24 hours. I suggest you get some medical advice. Incidentally, if you cut down nettles and leave them to die for 24 hours before touching them, they will not sting at all.

Comment: As Aleph said, nettle stings normally calm down more quickly than that, though some people are more sensitive than others. I would seek medical advice. If the area has been sprayed with herbicides or pesticides this can result in a more severe reaction.

Comment: I disagree that dead leaves don't sting - from personal experience! From a scientific perspective, the stings have two modes of action - one is mechanical (they have sharp silica tips that poke holes in you) and the other is chemical (they release various inflammatory compounds into the holes they make). The silica tips are resistant to decay, so being dead makes very difference to the mechanical irritation. The tips are fragile, so cutting them down is likely to damage many of the tips reducing the likelihood of stinging.

Comment: @Georgeofalltrades I guess some people are more pain-sensitive than others. I've seen the comment about "day old" dead nettles not stinging in print, and it works for me. But then I have been known to re-pot *opuntia* cacti without gloves, because wearing gloves is too clumsy ;)

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to get it checked out, its been going on a while now and not getting any better.

Comment: @SPlatten Is there a rash? Tbh, this doesn't sound related to the stinging nettles. Yes definitely get in to see a doctor.

Comment: No rash, just constant pins and needles

Comment: I would guess you have strained something and/or trapped a nerve - but I'm not a medic, and you need professional advice. Not wishing to scare you, but if it's "not getting any better" it may get *very much* worse over time, if it's not sorted out.

Comment: I went to the local walk in medical centre this morning, current opinion is that I’ve trapped a nerve, probably down to one of my visits at the gym.  Making appointment to see doctor to get it checked out.

Comment: Asking for medical advice seems off topic

Comment: I agree @SPlatten  Nettles would NOT cause this and gee, hate to say this but your LEFT hand might indicate your heart.  A pinched nerve from inflammation either at your left elbow or your wrist or even your shoulder blade area would cause tingling.  Do you feel this more in your first finger and thumb?  Or the last three fingers; little, ring and middle?  The latter would be the nerve junction at the elbow, the former would be carpal tunnel at your wrist. Oh!  I just read your latest comment, WRIST!? Nettles don't 'sting' like a bee, more like a jelly fish.  But very short term problem.

Comment: @alephzero  I too, hate wearing gloves.  Heck even shoes!  The plant world does cause us to veer into an awful lot of subjects closely related, grins!  Especially our nutrition and health.  You may not be a medic but you are correct by this 'non' medic's opinion...pinched or better 'trapped' nerve!  Docta Alephzero!

Comment: @stormy, when I went to the medical centre, the nurse said the same, but having checked me out, it isn't, so I'm booking in to see my Doctor this Friday.  Its a very odd feeling, like the blood is being pumped in hard and constantly, the end of my thumb and fingers feel like they want to burst.

Comment: @SPlatten So when they say this is NOT a nerve problem what do they say it MIGHT be?  I had damage to my shoulder rotator cuff muscles in a car accident.  Leaving my arm and hand either numb or tingling for years. What happens if you lie down, keeping your head above your heart level and propping up your entire arm under your armpit with a pillow keeping your hand higher than your head?  That should help drain the fluid from your hand that btw is causing the discomfort.  I would also wrap my hand and lower arm past the elbow with stretchy athletic wrap.  NOT TOO tight? Do you feel a heartbeat?

Comment: ...in your hand?

Comment: ...what is it that you do for a living?  Interesting that you work out with weights as that could definitely be a great cause for peripheral limb problems.  Let's go to chat and go over your workout program...grins, I am an expert with plants but also an expert (Exercise Specialist) in fitness for humans and other animals.  Your symptoms came on after a period of time. Think about what you were doing 24 to 48 hours earlier.  Are you lifting light weights using lots and lots of repetitions?  Are you lifting too quickly?  You should be doing 3 or 4 sets of 6 to 8 reps, the last rep very taxing?

Comment: Massage of your shoulder muscles, your elbow or your wrist should reduce the pins and needles.  Have you taken aspirin?  Aspirin should never be taken within 24 hours of a workout, but after that amt of time, aspirin is very beneficial.  Too early the muscle fibers have a hard time knitting back and will throw out the benefits of a workout.  By now, aspirin might help an awful lot.  Building strength if done correctly means breaking down the fibers of a muscle group and then allowing 48 hours to heal.  After healing, those fibers will be stronger!  A reason for doing very specific groups.

Comment: I’m a professional software engineer.  My workout is as follows:  10 minutes on stair master, 140 calories burn on cross trainer, 80 abdominal crunch with 35kg, 60 x 3 x 20 side side twists with 10 kg Medicean ball, 110kg leg crunch, 4x20x35 kg leg curls, 4x20x25 kg leg extensions , 110 kg leg swats, 3x15x40 kg chest press, 3x13x35 kg lateral pull downs, 4x12x20 kg barbell curls, 4x12x22.5 kg triceps press

Comment: @stormy, how do we go to chat I live in the UK, I will be back at my accommodation at around 19:00 tonight.

Comment: I've set it up, simply respond like normal and you should find yourself in chat.  If not go to the bottom of the page and click on the tiny 'chat'.  Usually works well. 7 pm?  You are 8 hours? ahead of us?  So it is  12:45 am now and you are at 8:45 am?  Ugh.  I have the swing shift to keep the fire going, kind of primitive but true.  Not the sharpest knife in the dishwasher at this time, sorry!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85688/discussion-between-stormy-and-splatten).